# How exclude folders for remove when using ( rm -rf *) on the parent dir

Tags: command-line, files, removing

i run the following command line to remove all files/dirs in directory :

```
       cd /home/abdennour/android/

       rm -rf *
```

the architecture of this directory is as following :

```
   /home/abdennour/android/
   /home/abdennour/android/documents/
   /home/abdennour/android/documents/medialib/
   /home/abdennour/android/documents/preview/
   /home/abdennour/android/fixtures/
   /home/abdennour/android/images/
   /home/abdennour/android/images/hard/
   /home/abdennour/android/images/mlibrary/
   /home/abdennour/android/images/mlibrary/thumbs/
   /home/abdennour/android/js/ 
  .....
```

i want to remove all with excluding the following directories :

```
  /home/abdennour/android/documents/
  /home/abdennour/android/images/mlibrary/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GLOBIGNORE` environment variable. Suppose that you want to delete everithing except `/home/abdennour/android/documents/` and `/home/abdennour/android/images/mlibrary/`, then you can do the following:

```
cd /home/abdennour/android/
export GLOBIGNORE="documents:images"
rm -rf *
cd images
export GLOBIGNORE="mlibrary"
rm -rf *
export GLOBIGNORE=""
```

Comment: BUT does not work when script runned from Sh file .

Answer (score -1):

As the list of those dirs you don't want to remove is pretty short and it doesn't seem to fit any obvious pattern, I think you will just have to move those dirs somewhere prior to deleting the rest.